# Scala udf check if df column value is in a list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am writing a scala UDF which takes values from a column and check if specific values in a list exists then do something and if some other value exists do something and so on. For example:

```
val listOfValues = List("001", "002", "003", "004", "005")

if ($"column".isin(listOfValues: _*) || (logic 2) && (logic 3)) "value 1"
else if ($"column".isin(listOfValues: _*) || (logic 3) || (logic 4)) "value 2"
else if ($"column".isin(listOfValues: _*) && (logic 4) && (logic 5)) "value 3"
else "value 4"
```

Now the problem is that `$"column".isin(listOfValues: _*)` returns a column but not a single true/false value. And I need there a true/false value by each row to use the condition correctly.

Any suggestions on how to check that df column contains those values in the list as a true/false?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a DF like the following:

```
+---+----+-----+
|ID |Type|Value|
+---+----+-----+
|ID1|001 |1    |
|ID1|002 |5    |
|ID2|A   |12   |
|ID3|A   |3    |
|ID3|B   |3    |
|ID3|002 |5    |
|ID4|A   |10   |
+---+----+-----+
```

you can create a UDF to check if a column value is in a List. For example:

```
val listOfValues = List("001", "002", "003", "004", "005")
def isInDef(p1: String): String = if (listOfValues.contains(p1) || (logic 2) && (logic 3)) "value 1"
                                  else if (listOfValues.contains(p1) || (logic 3) || (logic 4)) "value 2"
                                  else if (listOfValues.contains(p1) && (logic 4) && (logic 5)) "value 3"
                                  else "value 4"
val isIn = udf[String, String](isInDef)
```

Then you can use the UDF to create a new column with the correct value from the conditions:

```
df = df.withColumn("contain", isIn($"Type"))

+---+----+-----+-------+
|ID |Type|Value|contain|
+---+----+-----+-------+
|ID1|001 |1    |value 1|
|ID1|002 |5    |value 2|
|ID2|A   |12   |value 4|
|ID3|A   |3    |value 4|
|ID3|B   |3    |value 4|
|ID3|002 |5    |value 3|
|ID4|A   |10   |value 4|
+---+----+-----+-------+
```